# Specifying common modules and dependency in r.js

Tags: requirejs, dependencies

I am using requirejs and since the number of javascript files is growing, we are planning to use the requirejs optimizer. 
Since there are few 3rd party js like (jquery,angular,bootstrap) which is used by all the pages, I thought its a better idea to put all the dependency to the same file. 
Say we have 2 files, employee.js and manager.js and what I did in my build.js was

```
modules[{
name:"person",
include:["jQuery",
"angular",
"bootstrap"
]
},
{
name:"manager",
include:["jQuery",
"angular",
"bootstrap"
]
}]
```

is it possible to put the list of included modules in a common place and make this use this. 
The other question is how do I specify dependencies in this case? say Angular is dependent on jQuery. 
In requirejs, there was a configuration file where I can specify the deps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [bundle](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles) or you can create a common module as per the [official multipage example](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage) depending on what exactly you wish to achieve. You can use variables in your `build.js` to save yourself from typing the same dependencies over and over.

See also the [mainConfigFile](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#mainConfigFile) option for using the same configuration for build as you did for runtime.

Here's an example of a bundle definition:

```js
requirejs.config({
    bundles: {
        'primary': ['main', 'util', 'text', 'text!template.html'],
        'secondary': ['text!secondary.html']
    }
});

require(['util', 'text'], function(util, text) {
    //The script for module ID 'primary' was loaded,
    //and that script included the define()'d
    //modules for 'util' and 'text'
});
```

Here's the most relevant part of the build file in the multipage example (but you should study the example in full):

```js
modules: [
    //First set up the common build layer.
    {
        //module names are relative to baseUrl
        name: '../common',
        //List common dependencies here. Only need to list
        //top level dependencies, "include" will find
        //nested dependencies.
        include: ['jquery',
                  'app/lib',
                  'app/controller/Base',
                  'app/model/Base'
        ]
    },

    //Now set up a build layer for each page, but exclude
    //the common one. "exclude" will exclude
    //the nested, built dependencies from "common". Any
    //"exclude" that includes built modules should be
    //listed before the build layer that wants to exclude it.
    //"include" the appropriate "app/main*" module since by default
    //it will not get added to the build since it is loaded by a nested
    //require in the page*.js files.
    {
        //module names are relative to baseUrl/paths config
        name: '../page1',
        include: ['app/main1'],
        exclude: ['../common']
    },

    {
        //module names are relative to baseUrl
        name: '../page2',
        include: ['app/main2'],
        exclude: ['../common']
    }

]
```